# I need to convert rows to column for calendar app

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2017

Probaly a simple solution to this, but it elludes me.
I have a SQL-Server (2017) table like this:

| rn | wk | day | subj |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 202225 | mon | subj1 |
| 2 | 202225 | mon | subj2 |
| 3 | 202225 | mon | subj3 |
| 1 | 202225 | tue | subj4 |
| 2 | 202225 | tue | subj5 |
| 1 | 202225 | wed | subj6 |
| 2 | 202225 | wed | subj7 |
| 1 | 202226 | mon | subj8 |
| 2 | 202226 | mon | subj9 |
| 1 | 202226 | tue | subj10 |
| 1 | 202226 | wed | subj11 |
| 2 | 202226 | wed | subj12 |
| 3 | 202226 | wed | subj13 |

I want to transpose this table to this using T-sql:

| wk | mon | tue | wed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202225 | subj1 | subj4 | subj6 |
| 202225 | subj2 | subj5 | subj7 |
| 202225 | subj3 | NULL | NULL |
| 202226 | subj8 | subj10 | subj11 |
| 202226 | subj9 | NULL | subj12 |
| 202226 | NULL | NULL | subj13 |

I tried using PIVOT, but the aggregate MAX function only gives me one record per week for the wk column. What is the correct / best SQL solution?

This is what I tried:

```
select * from (select wk, subj, day from mytable ) d 
pivot (max(subj) for day in (mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun)) piv;
```

Comment: Seems like you need a `ROW_NUMBER` too, but what rows are assigned to each week would be completely arbitrary with no column to order the values on.

Comment: I have row numbers available, I have added them to the table as I have them now.

Comment: please show your tried pivot query

Comment: please update your question with that query

Comment: You need to include the runing number `rn` in the sub-query `d`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a simple pivot, or (what I and many others prefer) conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT wk,
       MAX(CASE day WHEN 'mon' THEN subj END) AS mon,
       MAX(CASE day WHEN 'tue' THEN subj END) AS tue,
       MAX(CASE day WHEN 'wed' THEN subj END) AS wed
FROM (VALUES(1,202225,'mon','subj1'),
            (2,202225,'mon','subj2'),
            (3,202225,'mon','subj3'),
            (1,202225,'tue','subj4'),
            (2,202225,'tue','subj5'),
            (1,202225,'wed','subj6'),
            (2,202225,'wed','subj7'),
            (1,202226,'mon','subj8'),
            (2,202226,'mon','subj9'),
            (1,202226,'tue','subj10'),
            (1,202226,'wed','subj11'),
            (2,202226,'wed','subj12'),
            (3,202226,'wed','subj13'))V(rn,wk,day,subj)
GROUP BY rn,
         wk
ORDER BY wk,
         rn;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=38d14788294ba36e60eb2ac7f110f59d)